# Каким селектором найти все элементы с ::after в html?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Есть несколько несколько span:

```
<span class="name">1 ::after</span> (тут не уверен, что корректно написал)
<span class="name">2 </span>
<span class="name">3 </span>
```

У одного из span есть элемент ::After(выводит иконку).

Каким селектором все элементы у которых есть ::after?

Comment: XPath не может использовать. нужно использовать `By.cssSelector("span.name:after")`

Comment: Можно и css, однако такой элемент не хочет находить.

Comment: значит пиши полный CSS. в=проблема в пути

Answer (score 0):

`XPath` не может использовать. нужно использовать `By.cssSelector("span.name:after")`